# Python numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've got a NumPy array say, ***index=[4,5,8,2]***. The elements of this array are basically indexes of a list of strings called ***doclist***. Now I need to copy the strings from the position ***4,5,2,8*** of ***doclist*** to another list ***summary***. The size of the ***index***, ***doclist*** are user-defined. I've implemented the code but I need to make it compact. Please give some suggestions, I'm a newbie to python.

Comment: Can you share your code to try to improve it ?

Comment: `summary = doclist[index]` should be enough (assuming doclist is a numpy array)

Comment: `index=[4,5,8,2]` - `index` is a list, not an ndarray.

Comment: `Please give some suggestions,` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem

Comment: If `doclist` is a list, there's no value in `index` being an numpy array instead of a list.  Just iterate on `index` and select the strings one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what is meant.

```
summary=[doclist[i] for i in index]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think it'll serve the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: You are Most Welcome